# ERROR: DexGuard Gradle plugin: Android Gradle plugin version is not supported. (4.0.0), supported versions include [2.3.0:3.6.*]

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dexguard

I'm using android studio 4.0 and my Gradle version is 4.0.0 . how to add dexguard version 8.7 to my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the lasted dexguard release:

> The DexGuard Gradle plugin is compatible with the Android Gradle
> plugin versions [2.3.x, 3.6.x].

Rollback to a 3.6.x and it should work. Yeah, thats bad :/